# Force loop containing asynchronous task to maintain sequence

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, printing, backgroundworker

Something tells me this might be a stupid question and I have in fact approached my problem from the wrong direction, but here goes.

I have some code that loops through all the documents in a folder - The alphabetical order of these documents in each folder is important, this importance is also reflected in the order the documents are printed. Here is a simplified version:

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder))
      {
          fileCounter++;

          // Print file, referencing a previously instantiated word application object
          wordApp.Documents.Open(...)
          wordApp.PrintOut(...)
          wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(...)
      }
```

It seems (and I could be wrong) that the PrintOut code is asynchronous, and the application sometimes gets into a situation where the documents get printed out of order. This is confirmed because if I step through, or place a long enough `Sleep()` call, the order of all the files is correct.

How should I prevent the next print task from starting before the previous one has finished?

I initially thought that I could use a `lock(someObject){}` until I remembered that they are only useful for preventing multiple threads accessing the same code block. This is all on the same thread.

There are some events I can wire into on the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` object:  `DocumentOpen`, `DocumentBeforeClose` and  `DocumentBeforePrint`

I have just thought that this might actually be a problem with the print queue not being able to  accurately distinguish lots of documents that are added within the same second. This can't be the problem, can it?

*As a side note, this loop is within the code called from the DoWork event of a `BackgroundWorker` object. I'm using this to prevent UI blocking and to feedback the progress of the process.*

Answer (score 1):

Your event-handling approach seems like a good one. Instead of using a loop, you could add a handler to the `DocumentBeforeClose` event, in which you would get the next file to print, send it to Word, and continue. Something like this:

```
List<...> m_files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder);
wordApp.DocumentBeforeClose += ProcessNextDocument;

...

void ProcessNextDocument(...)
{
    File file = null;
    lock(m_files)
    {
        if (m_files.Count > 0)
        {
            file = m_files[m_files.Count - 1];
            m_files.RemoveAt(m_files.Count - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // Done!
        }
    }

    if (file != null)
    {
        PrintDocument(file);
    }
}

void PrintDocument(File file)
{
    wordApp.Document.Open(...);
    wordApp.Document.PrintOut(...);
    wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [Application.PrintOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.printout%28v=office.14%29.aspx) specifies whether the printing should take place in the background or not. By setting it to `false` it will work synchronously.